# problem with boost.test with old version

Tags: c++, include, boost-test

I'm trying to use `boost.test` on a remote system with boost 1.33.1. On my pc this little example from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html works:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp> // I've changed here

int add( int i, int j ) { return i+j; }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )   // <--- line 7
{
// seven ways to detect and report the same error:
BOOST_CHECK( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );        // #1 continues on error

BOOST_REQUIRE( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );      // #2 throws on error

if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
  BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );            // #3 continues on error

if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
  BOOST_FAIL( "Ouch..." );             // #4 throws on error

if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 ) throw "Ouch..."; // #5 throws on error

BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE( add( 2,2 ) == 4,  // #6 continues on error
                     "add(..) result: " << add( 2,2 ) );

BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( add( 2,2 ), 4 );   // #7 continues on error
}
```

but on the remote system the file `unit_test.hpp` doesn't exist. On my pc the file `unit_test_framework.hpp` is simply:

```
// deprecated
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

and it is present on the main system. So I tried to change the include to:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test_framework.hpp>
```

but the compiler says:

```
main.cpp:7: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

what's this? How to solve it?

Comment: On which system did you change the include?

Comment: Could you please tell us which version of boost is installed on your remote system?

Comment: remote: 1.33.1, local: 1.36.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Boost 1.33 use:

```
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>
```

in place of:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

and also before the #include add:

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
```

or you'll get a linker error

Answer (score 0):

If your version of boost is older than 1.33, you should try renaming `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` to `BOOST_AUTO_UNIT_TEST`, and it shouldn't break compilation on newer versions of boost.

See these Boost.Test [1.33 Release Notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/test/doc/release_notes.html#v1_33_0) :

> BOOST_AUTO_UNIT_TEST renamed to
>   BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE. Old name still
>   provided but deprecated

Comment: I've exactly the same message. I think that `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` is defined in `boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp`. But if I include it I got: `undefined reference to `init_unit_test_suite(int, char**)'`

Comment: @wiso: `undefined reference` is actually a very different error ! You have to link against the boost.test library

Comment: I'm already using `-lboost_unit_test_framework`, what do I have to link?

Answer (score 0):

What's the boost version on your target platform? Are you using an old version there?

Since you are using a header only version of boost.test (you include the boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp header and not boost/test/unit_test.hpp), can't you just copy the working boost installation from your PC to the target machine and instruct your compiler to use it?